# messed up my fonts after uninstalling emacs

Tags: fonts, emacs

so I installed emacs today and then removed it

```
sudo apt install emacs
```

then when I uninstalled i did

```
sudo apt remove --purge emacs
sudo apt autoremove
```

but then my Terminal font became taller, so did my terminal
here's a picture
[image]

basically, the aspect ratio of a cell in the terminal changed, and it is really bothering me

Comment: Have you tried running `reset` or looking at `tset`?

Comment: @NerdOfCode yeah i tried  that, i also tried reseting gconf and reseting fonts.conf but nothing